# Managing Ruby On Rails with multiple regions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git

I've been thinking about taking my SAAS app to international markets and was just wondering how others handle this type of situation with regards to the code base.

Obviously there are things like validations which need to be updated (validating mobile numbers in different countries) but also billing changes.

I foresee there being quite a few differences in how the platform will run but ideally would hate to have to manage multiple versions of the Rails source code in different repositories. (So if I fix a bug in the US version, I'd also have to switch to the FRANCE version and apply it there too).

If I kept it all in the one repository, there would be annoying things like;

> 1. Managing multiple robots.txt and schedule.rb files (for cron)
> 2. Different website promotions and advertising (though I guess this can be DB based)
> 3. Turning off features and hyperlinks per region. (US has this feature but France has that feature etc)
> 4. Source code might get messy with tailored partials (_some_partial.en-US.html.erb and _some_parth.en-FR.html.erb) etc
> 5. Creating code and features will require developers to be mindful of the consequences across multiple regions. (If I build FEATURE-A for the US platform, I'll have to build code to make sure this is turned off when viewed on the France platform etc).

Solutions so far;

> 1. Same codebase for all regions; but use ugly if statements for logic (If US? elsif France? end)
> 2. Separate repositories for each region
> 3. Separate github branches for each region and I work off master and merge that into production_france etc (which has france related commits also)
> 4. Rails engines??

How would sites like `Taskrabbit` (They just launched in the UK) or `yelp` do this across regions?

Comment: Instead of ugly if statements you could use configuration files which are specific to that locale which get loaded based on your environment setting.

Comment: +1 for configuration files. For instance, store the regex used to verify phone numbers in a configuration file for each region in the config file. In your model, just validate based on the current region.

Comment: To play devil's advocate, I think the advantages of different code bases outweigh the advantages of having one monolithic app.  You can test features, upgrades on a per region basis before instead of rolling them out to everyone, you can taylor your app to different regions/economies more easily.  You would already be in a position where you would need to test your app for every region.  I'd rather maintain more simpler apps than 1 large complex one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a right or wrong answer to this, but here's an opinion.

1. Make your advertising site an entirely separate codebase. In projects I've worked on, it can be a real advantage to implement changes for marketing without having to deploy a new version of the entire product ecosystem.  Keep them separate as it's easy to separate concerns.  You don't really want to be running the entire test/deployment process against a simple content change on the marketing site.
2. I would recommend looking at the existing i18n plugins/solutions for Rails and decide if those approaches are relevant to your product.  Most methods of solving this seem to be to create YML files per region with customised strings/settings, etc, then having the i18n class pull the appropriate things from the YML file section.
3. I would assume that each region could be decided per user?  I've done this in the past where I set the user's region in the user model.  This can include timezone, language, etc.  Then I can change the experience for each user individually.  You could scope all i18n options via the user model, so when you need to obtain something per user, it's filtered via the user's region which then extends on to i18n/YML file settings.
4. Will different regions really need different features?  This is the one factor that seems to complicate things.  If you could re-architect the code/product to make all features the same, it might make things simpler.